# ClassNotFoundException after upgrade to Grails 2.4.0

Tags: spring, grails

I upgraded my Grails project from grails-2.3.7 to grails-2.4.0 and followed the guide http://grails.org/doc/2.4.x/guide/upgradingFrom23.html. However, trying to run the app now yields the stack trace below. How do I fix this?

```
| Running Grails application
| Error 2014-06-12 15:45:55,788 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplicationPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotatedElementUtils
Message: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplicationPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotatedElementUtils
    Line | Method
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotatedElementUtils
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils
->>  366 | run       in java.net.URLClassLoader$1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|    355 | run       in     ''
|    354 | findClass in java.net.URLClassLoader
|    425 | loadClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
|    262 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
| Error Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

Answer (score 0):

Please run

```
grails dependency-report
```

And check that your application is not pulling in an older version of Spring. If you can paste the output into the question, you should see an older version of some Spring JAR in your dependency report, which is causing the issue. Grails 2.4 requires Spring 4.0.5 or above